# Is any choice of electric and vector potentials valid, as long as the correct gauge transformation exists?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge

For example, in general one would not choose a gauge with $\phi \neq 0$ and $\vec{A}=0$ because that simply gives you the electrostatic case where $\vec{B}=0$. However one can transform this into $\phi'=0$ and $\vec{A'}\neq 0$ by:

$$ 0 = \phi - \partial_t\psi \to \partial_t \psi = \phi \ ; \ \vec{A'}=\nabla \psi.$$

Implying that the original choice of potentials is "valid", even though it clearly is limited to specific cases. Can someone alleviate my confusion?

Comment: How does that transformation imply that the original choice of potentials is valid? It doesn't. Potentials are valid when they produce correct EM fields E,B.